# triggering the dependant builds to run it as the independant one as per the choice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm setting up the pipeline in jenkins it have the dependant jobs since it needs the parameter form the previous builds but when it is triggered it should not wait for the previous builds it should be triggered and the build should be runs independantly.

I have tried this by using the conditional buildstep plugin.It too depends on the previous builds and the parameters from them.

The user must be able to choose their own builds to get triggered for the builds though it is the dependant one ..it shouldn't wait for the previous builds ,the user desired jobs should start run for the builds

Comment: show your pipeline code.

Comment: Who triggers the builds?